# How to synchronise persistence contextes between two different applications sharing same database?

Tags: database, jpa, persistence

I have two apps which share a common database. The second app doesn't store any data but uses data produced by the first one. They both use JPA with cache enabled. Problem is when I update the database with my first app, the second one's cache is not. I'd like to have the second one refreshed as soon as the first one has updated the database. Is there a built in "messaging"/"trigger" mechanism to tell the second app to evict some entities from the cache, so as to reload them on the next call on these entities?

I use EclipseLink, but ideally there would be a standard way of doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any standard process. If you have 2 EntityManagerFactory objects then you have to inform them that something has changed elsewhere (and update your L2 cache). Same goes if you have some non-JPA process elsewhere that updates the database contents.

Look at your RDBMS and see if that has some mechanism for notifying a listener process when some table(s) are changed

Comment: Yep. Thanks. For EclipseLink I found this tutorial, although it looks like it's only for Oracle dbs... http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DCN

Comment: OK, got it working using jdbc with LISTEN and some polling on the java side + create a trigger on the tables which require a cache eviction.